# How can I output each letter of a prewritten word on a new line?

Tags: assembly, x86-16, emu8086

The task is to write an exe program (16 bit) that will display a prerecorded string (we use variables) in the following order. In the first line 1 letter from the line, in the second 2, in the third 3, etc. to the last character in the variable string.

Can anyone help as I don't understand this assembler at all((

That's all I'm capable of:

```
.MODEL TINY
.STACK 100h 


code:
    xor cx, cx
    mov cl, 5   
@1: mov dx, mess1
    add dx, cx
    mov ah, 9
    int 21h 
    
    mov dx, offset crlf
    mov ah, 9
    int 21h
    
    sub cx, 1               
    cmp cl, 0              
    jg @1
    mov ah,04Ch             
    mov al,1h
    int 21h  
    
    mess1 db "Artem$"
    crlf db 10, 13, "$"

end code
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need two DOS functions: [AH=9 WRITE $-TEMINATED STRING TO STANDARD OUTPUT](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2562.htm)
and [AH=2 WRITE CHARACTER FROM DL TO STANDARD OUTPUT](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2554.htm).
Let's load one character to `DL`, print it using `INT21h/AH=2`, then print the string `crlf` using `INT21h/AH=9` and repeat in the loop `CX` times.

```
code:               ; Let CX keep the number of characters in mess1.
    xor cx, cx
    mov cl, 5       ; OK, but it's shorter to use mov cx,5 instead.
```

This is wrong, we need the register DL for other purpose.

```
;    @1:mov dx, mess1 
;        add dx, cx
;        mov ah, 9
;        int 21h
```

Let's use other register to keep the address of each character, preferably register `SI`:

```
    mov si, offset mess1
```

The main loop starts here:

```
@1:     mov dl,[si]  ; Load one character to DL.        
        inc si       ; Prepare the address of the next character.
        mov ah,2     ; Print the character from DL. 
        int 21h
```

Now it's time to print `crlf` as a string:

```
    mov dx,offset crlf
    mov ah,9
    int 21h
```

Loop to print the remaining characters. SI points to the next character, CX is the loop counter.

```
    sub cx, 1               
    cmp cl, 0              
    jg @1
```

This could work but more elegant is `loop @1` or

```
    dec cx
    jnz @1
```

All five characters were printed on new lines. Now it's time to terminate the program.

```
    mov ah,04Ch             
    mov al,1h
    int 21h
```

`.MODEL TINY` produces DOS COM program which may be alternatively terminated with a simple instruction `ret`.